# mvvm update calculated fields

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Do you know best practices in `wpf+mvvm` to update Calculated fields?
What I can do instead `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Summary))`?

Also calculated field can be in another viewmodel and this viewmodel should not know about all dependences.

This is my code :

```
public class Model
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Summary => Prop1 + Prop2;
}

public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Model Model { get; }

    public int Prop1
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.Prop1;
        }
        set
        {
            Model.Prop1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Summary));
        }
    }

    public int Prop2
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.Prop2;
        }
        set
        {
            Model.Prop2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Summary));
        }
    }

    public int Summary => Model.Summary;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `OnPropertyChanged` on the calculated property is perfectly acceptable. If you have a relatively simple model like the one you wrote that'll be enough.

If you have multiple calculated properties on the model, you might consider creating a method to call all of them from a single place, instead of calling each one from every property.

Something like this:

```
public int Prop1
{
    get
    {
        return _prop1;
    }
    set
    {
        _prop1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        NotifyCalculatedProperties();
    }
}

public int Calc1 { get { /* ... */ } }
public int Calc2 { get { /* ... */ } }
public int Calc3 { get { /* ... */ } }

public void NotifyCalculatedProperties()
{
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Calc1));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Calc2));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Calc3));
}
```

In case the calculated properties exist in a different model, you can register in that Model\VM to the source's `PropertyChanged` event, and then invoke the change notification there.

Like that:

```
void ModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "Prop1")
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Calc1));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Calc2));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Calc3));
}
```

Just don't forget to unsubscribe when the Model\VM changes, or you'll have a memory leak on your hands.

Lastly, you can always use the Messenger to pass messages between unrelated VMs, though you should use caution since it's a very powerful tool, and can easily be misused.
I don't know what MVVM framework you're using, but each has it's own implementation. You can find more general details on the Messenger pattern here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx